# WordPress - Stop Process for "WP Background Processing"

Tags: wordpress, background-process

I'm using WP Background Processing https://github.com/deliciousbrains/wp-background-processing , to create a background process that move some files to another server.

All works well, I'm able to select the files, add theme to the queue and start the move. Everything works nice but once the process is started i cannot stop it.
I want to be able to stop the background process in case i change my mind during the file transfer.

I created an ajax function that calls this php function.

```
function me_stop_moving_files(){
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT `option_name` AS `name`, `option_value` AS `value`
            FROM  $wpdb->options
            WHERE `option_name` LIKE %s
            ORDER BY `option_name`";


    $wild = '%';
    $find = 'wp_example_process';
    $like = $wild . $wpdb->esc_like( $find ) . $wild;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($sql,$like) );

    foreach ( $results as $result ){
        delete_option($result->name);
    }

    $this->process_all->cancel_process();
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('wp_example_process_cron');

    die('completed');
}
```

Where cancel_process() is a method of class wp-background-process.php. At first glance it seems the process is stopped but sooner or later it starts again.

Does anyone has any experience with this library and can point me in the right direction ?

Comment: You can learn from WooCommerce. The function kill_process() of class WC_Background_Process maybe what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the library before, but looking at the code, it seems that the processes could be canceled by calling the class method like this:

```
function me_stop_moving_files(){
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT `option_name` AS `name`, `option_value` AS `value`
            FROM  $wpdb->options
            WHERE `option_name` LIKE %s
            ORDER BY `option_name`";


    $wild = '%';
    $find = 'wp_example_process';
    $like = $wild . $wpdb->esc_like( $find ) . $wild;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($sql,$like) );

    foreach ( $results as $result ){
        delete_option($result->name);
    }

    $WP_Background_Process = new WP_Background_Process();
    $Cancel_process = $WP_Background_Process->cancel_process();
    die('completed');
}
```